# How to change repeating interval of AlarmManager at runtime in Android

Tags: android

I have written the following `AlarmManager` to start a `Service` which will download a file at specified interval:

```
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    Intent downloader = new Intent(mActivity, FileDownloadService.class);
    downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity, 0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

From the other part of the application, I get the value for repeating interval to run the `Service`. The value for repeating interval change on daily basis.

How can we change the `AlarmManager` interval at runtime as the above code will be executed only once?

For example, on day 1 I want the repeating interval to be 15 minutes and on day 2 I want the interval to be 2 hours.

How can I change the repeating interval dynamically?

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar: please do not just add `code ticks`. Fix all problems such as grammar, capitalization, "hi" and "thanks in advance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the value 15 minutes inside your pending intent as an extra. When your code gets triggered by the alarm manager, get the current value, increment it as per your needs and reset the extra in the intent which holds the value.

Edit : Use alarmManager.set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation); at every new invocation of your code.

Comment: so as per my understanding, i have to call the alarmManager.setRepeating() method again..

Comment: @geekoraul anyway we could get a code example here?

Comment: @geekoraul did you get a solution for this question? , please help it's urgent.

Comment: @geekoraul means how to do repeatetive time interval for alarm manager